# How can I combine these two arrays into a hash?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have these two following arrays:

`Classification.product.map{|p|[p.description, p.id]}`

```
[["Antiques", 1], ["Art", 2], ["Auto", 3], ["Books", 4], ["Clothing & Accessories", 5], ["Collectibles/Trading Cards", 6], ["Electronics & Computers", 7], ["Event Decoration", 8], ["Furniture", 9], ["Home & Garden", 10], ["Instruments", 11], ["Kids & Baby", 12], ["Movies & Music", 13], ["Property Rentals", 14], ["Shoes/Sneakers", 15], ["Sports & Outdoors", 16], ["Tickets", 17], ["Toys & Games", 18], ["Video Games", 19], ["Other", 20]]
```

and

`Classification.service.map{|p|[p.description, p.id]}`

```
[["Beauty", 21], ["Child Care", 22], ["Cleaning", 23], ["Computer/Technology", 24], ["Culinary", 25], ["Custom Goods", 26], ["Decorating/Interior Design", 27], ["Fashion", 28], ["Fitness", 29], ["Health/Wellbeing", 30], ["Home Improvement", 31], ["Landscaping/Yard", 32], ["Odd Jobs/Handymen", 33], ["Organizing", 34], ["Event Planning", 35], ["Pet Care", 36], ["Photography/Video", 37], ["Professional Services", 38], ["Tutoring/Instruction", 39], ["Other", 40]]
```

What I want to do is create a hash where each key is an element from the first array and each value is an element from the second array.

So, ideally it would look something like this:

```
{["Antiques", 1]=>["Beauty", 21], ["Art", 2]=>["Child Care", 22], etc.}
```

There happens to be an equal amount of classifications for products and services; but, in case they aren't equal, I want the code to still work. So it should insert a blank key/value if there is less classifications of one than the other.

How would I do this/ can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
Hash[
    Classification.product.map{|p|[p.description, p.id]}.zip(
        Classification.service.map{|p|[p.description, p.id]})]
```

This is a bit confusing one-liner. Most importantly there are two things I use:

- `Hash[a]` where `a` is array where each element is an array with two elements generates a hash where key is the first element and value - the second one.
- zip "zips" two arrays thus generating an array of arrays with two elements.

Comment: Yours returns an array where the key is the product.description and the value is the service.id

Comment: it looks like this: {"Antiques"=>21, "Art"=>22, "Auto"=>23, "Books"=>24, "Clothing & Accessories"=>25, "Collectibles/Trading Cards"=>26, "Electronics & Computers"=>27, "Event Decoration"=>28, "Furniture"=>29, "Home & Garden"=>30, "Instruments"=>31, "Kids & Baby"=>32, "Movies & Music"=>33, "Property Rentals"=>34, "Shoes/Sneakers"=>35, "Sports & Outdoors"=>36, "Tickets"=>37, "Toys & Games"=>38, "Video Games"=>39, "Other"=>40}

Comment: @Snubber sorry I misread the question. I am doing more than I should have

Comment: @Snubber fixed now sorry for that.

Comment: it now returns a hash of each classification of a service

Comment: @Snubber actaully you need to use the two arrays as produced in your question. I have copied this in the one-liner but now it is even more ugly. You should consider keeping those arrays in separate temporary variables to improve readability.

Comment: I modified what you gave me ealier for the desired result. Here it is: Hash[Classification.product.map{|p|[p.description, p.id]}.zip(Classification.service.map{|p|[p.description, p.id]})] if you update your answer with this I'll check it as answered